# Changing Drawer Layout Animation color

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawer

I am trying to play around with animation and drawer so i am using the **drawer sample code** available on the [Android Developer Website](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

For starters i have specified `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in drawer layout and its showing white color for a small interval when ever i try to open the navigation drawer. I would like to change that color to some other color.
[image]

I would like to use `android:animateLayoutChanges` property because it helps me with the other smooth animations but i would like to get rid of that white colored navigation drawer that appears for a brief moment.